# In WordPress, how do I get CiviCRM to show up on the internal WP account toolbar for Users to access it

Tags: wordpress, user-account, menu

I have set up and configured WP permissions, and I have set up ACLs in CRM. I have done both before in other databases, but I have no idea why Users I set up can't see the CiviCRM logo on their internal WP tool bar to access CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give them civicrm permissions starting with access_civicrm. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

ACL's are to limit what data they see.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. Accessto CiviCRM backend and API must be checked in permissions even though it is advised to only give to trusted users. Check box does not actually give backend and api access.